# How can I use just one connection to MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've a group of functions that executes some queries. This is my code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

async function createDatabase() {
  MongoClient.connect(urlMongoDB, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Database created!");
      db.close();
  });
}

async function countCollections(callback) {
  MongoClient.connect(urlMongoDB, function(err, db) {
    if (err) callback(error);
    var dbo = db.db(nameDatabase);
    dbo.collection(nameCollections).find(query).count();
  });
}

async function saveCollections() {
   // similar code
}


// I call these function in an another function (into the same source):

async function connectionMongo() {
   // my code
}
module.exports = connectionMongo;
```

I would like to modify the code in order to use just one connection into "connectionMongo()" function. I've tried in this way:

```
async function connectionMongo() {
  MongoClient.connect(urlMongoDB, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db(nameDatabase);
    await createDatabase(dbo);
}
```

and I've removed "MongoClient.connect" in all other functions, but I obtain the error:

```
await createDatabase(dbo);
    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

How can I modify correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to annotate the callback function that you pass into `MongoClient.connect` with `async` in order to use `await` inside of it:

```js
MongoClient.connect(urlMongoDB, async function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db(nameDatabase);
    await createDatabase(dbo);
})
```